# Populate wizard field odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How populate field email on wizard from context?

For example:

This work:

```
email = fields.Char(string = 'Email')

context="{'default_email': email}"
```

Not working:

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string = 'User', select=True)

context="{'default_user_id.email': email}"
```

I want pass to wizard email from selected user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want when you create a `user_id` from the many2one field when you click on create and edit option:

```xml
<field name="user_id" context="{'default_mail':mail}" />
```

When you create a user the mail will have the same value of the field mail every time.

> don't pass the context to many2one record in action but in the view definition

Comment: in your answer you've used a quote (don't pass the context...). If it is indeed a quote, could you provide a source?

Comment: No worries. I meant that in your comment the last sentence (_don't pass the context..._) is a quote (starts with `>`). A quote usualy means it is from another source (eg. Odoo documentation, comment from a core Odoo developer), in which case there should be a link to the website where the quote comes from. If this is not a quote but your own statement, then just remove the `>` symbol from the beginning of the last sentence ;)

Comment: mmmm ok i use it to mark it like a note? is there a way to mark some thing like a Note?